# JavaScript - Display timestamp in better format

Tags: javascript, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

I'm using Javascript. My data contains timestamp like this:

```
2013-01-08T06:17:37+03:00
```

I want to display it in clear format, it should be: `2013-01-08 06:17:37`
no need to other info.

I tried `SimpleDateFormat` and `.toUTCString()` with no luck

Comment: check this link http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: Try: ('0' + timestamp.getDate()).slice(-2) + '.' + 
    ('0' + (timestamp.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '.' + 
    timestamp.getFullYear();